# Capitalizing first letter in string with ::first-letter. bug?

Tags: html, css

I stumbled across this weird behaviour recently while trying to find a generic front-end way of capitalizing **the first letter** in a string. Normally, i would just call it quits, but i kept on trying to find a solution. However, that's when i came across this strange behaviour.

snippet:

```css
.capitalizeWord::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<p class="capitalizeWord">
  <span>
    <i></i>
  test1></span>hello
</p>

<!-- example 2 -->
<p class="capitalizeWord">
  <span style="float:left;"> <!--float causes it to work -->
    <i></i>
  test2></span>hello
</p>
```

According to [caniuse ::first-letter](https://caniuse.com/#search=first-letter) chrome is supporting this.

So, my first question is: *What is causing this behaviour?*  <kbd>This has been "somewhat" answered in the comments</kbd>

My initial thought was that the compiler interpreted the `<i>`-tags as chars. But no, the issue is still prevalent when they're removed.
Can anyone else verify that they are experiencing the same results? 
Posting image for reference if your browser isn't seeing what mine is:

[image]

Anyhow, my second question: Is there a frontend way to accomplish the result of `test2` but with `test1`'s structure?

> Off-topic but still relevant to answer my first question. See below

#### Update:

After some discussion in the comments, the problem has been narrowed down to be about the `<i>`-tag after all.

However, I would still classify this as a bug. Here's why:

An empty `<i></i>` [**should not**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#x50) trigger `::first-letter`. Like, that should be self-evident by just looking at the name of the **selector**.

*Why is `::first-letter` triggered by a non letter character (an <kbd>EMPTY</kbd> html-**tag** in this case), and then stops looking within that scope when nothing has been found in the EMPTY  tags, which isn't where the root-elements (p/div) scope ends... Like, whyyyyyyyyyy?*

I can break the entire selector by just doing:

```css
.box::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
  <!-- wooohoo, works! -->
</div>

<div class="box">
  <i></i>some text
  <!-- doesn't work now... I broke it, without adding ANY characters/letters to the dom -->
</div>

<span class="box">
   some text 
<!-- doesn't work now... I broke it again, just changed to a span-tag -->
</span>

<span class="box" style="display:block;">
   some text 
<!-- wooohoo, works! -->
</span>
```

Maybe this is me being stubborn, but, i really hate this approach they've taken with this selector. It really could have been used as **"the way to go"** for capitalizing strings on the web, instead of all these javascript workarounds has had to be created in its place.

Comment: you floated the element so it's removed from normal flow and H become the first letter, since the span is now a block level element

Comment: @TemaniAfif if this is accurate => in test1, why isnt the `T` capitalized then?

Comment: because it's not the first letter, you have `<i></i>` before

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see, makes a little more sense now. However, `<i></i>` doesn't contain anything, thus shouldn't be affecting `::first-letter` ?

Comment: `The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other conten` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Comment: @TemaniAfif this doesn't explain anything that isn't already clear. The fact that an empty `<i></i>` is triggering the `::first-letter` selector isn't explained by this.

Comment: *but only when not preceded by other content* : how it doesn't explain .. **not preceded** by other content

Comment: You forgot the last part of that sentance: `... but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).`. Also, it is not preceded by other content. the issue remains.

Comment: it depend where you apply inline-block and where you expect the first-letter to be .. but it work fine with inline-block: https://jsfiddle.net/ov3480aq/1/

Comment: because I don't think they will list all the possible element as they are plenty ... anyway, wait and someone will give you a more accurate explanation

Comment: `Also, it is not preceded by other content. the issue remains` : how the issue remains?

Comment: From what you and I have talked about. This is where my problem with this whole thing lies: https://jsfiddle.net/ov3480aq/3/

Comment: You have the `i` which is an element preceding the text and first-letter won't work .. if you are not convinced and you think I am wrong, I have nothing more to add ... probably someone else will give a better explanation

Comment: Using `>` instead of `&gt;` looks highly irritating to me.

Comment: your snippet works in FF/Win10 just FYI

Comment: In Firefox/Arch Linux both examples have a capitalized first letter.

Comment: first-letter apply to block level element, it's won't work if you apply to span or any inline element (changing to block or inline-block make it working)

Comment: you could try `.box, .box *::first-letter {text-transform: uppercase;}`

Comment: Not sure if it would work though

Comment: nah, that would only apply, if the content would be inside the empty `<i></i>`

Comment: The browser is looking at `<i></i>` for the first letter, does not find one and stops. Why should it look at the next character?

Comment: _In your opinion_ and thus I've voted to close as Primarily Opinion Based. I do wish that the specs were clear about this.

Comment: you can wait for answers, you aren't obliged to reply to all comments. and there was only 1h since you asked, it's still early .. and please don't edit your question to include "I am closing .."

Comment: don't judge people based on reputation, it means nothing ... I know at least 3 users that can give you accurate answers but they aren't yet here and will probably come later .. and all these attempt was trying to answer the question that you are editing a lot, so it's logically to get answer because people will try to find while you change the question and when they notice this they delete.

Comment: and if you want to close the question then better delete it and don't add the "closing" banner yourself.

Comment: If the question is "why doesn't this work", then it is a valid question and should be kept open (barring a duplicate). If the question is "in my opinion the CSS spec should work differently" then that's in fact not a question at all and should be deleted .Questions should be closed only when they are off-topic and don't 'deserve' answers based on the site's scope. Questions should be deleted when they don't hold any value for future readers.

Comment: By the way, floating the element doesn't work to capitalize the `h` in Firefox. I don't know if that's a bug in Firefox or if it's the other browsers that are not spec-compliant.

Comment: @Joel I didn't miss it, I simply did not address it on purpose. But to address it now: no, you can't do that crossbrowser (as my Firefox comment indicates). Yes, you can do it in Chrome and IE, as your test2 example works (it has the same structure as test1). Either way, you should not try to target naked content. If you want to target something, wrap that something in tags (and give it a class/ID)

Comment: @Joel styles are not structure. Styles *can* affect structure. At any rate, there are myriad ways to solve your problem if you're willing to cast aside the insistence of using your provided test structure. PS - another word for (HTML) structure is markup. Either way, both terms refer to the HTML, not styles (including inline styles). And since you only care about WebKit browsers, then the answer to the question you asked is "yes - what you have is already working".

Comment: @Rob: < is not the first letter, as it's neither a typographic letter unit, nor a punctuation mark that may appear before a typographic letter unit for the purposes of ::first-letter. If an element's first formatted line begins with <, that element has no first letter.

Comment: @Salman A: Did you really take their one opinionated comment and extrapolate that their *entire question* is POB? It certainly doesn't look to me like Joel is intent on pushing any agenda and is mostly looking for a solution to their problem regardless of what they think should be the correct behavior.

Comment: @BoltClock after 20+ comments the question was changed to whether `<i></i>` should or should not be considered as the first letter. And at least 3 other people agree with me (just look at the update part).

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why all of you think a question is POB just because the asker stated an opinion in their question. The original question(s) remain: what's causing this behavior and how can they achieve their desired result? And those are the *primary* questions they want answered.

Comment: @BoltClock if you/someone could find the expected behavior in the specs then I will retract my vote. Otherwise it is opinion based... I think vs you think (I already mentioned that `<i></i>foo` should become `<i><::firstletter></::firstletter></i>foo` but I cannot provide a reference for it.

Comment: @Salman A: I'm waiting to hear back from one of the spec editors because I don't think it's clear from the spec either. The spec mentions "images and inline tables" but doesn't say anything about empty inline boxes. I suspect those count too, but I do want to get confirmation if possible. What's clear though is that this behavior is not interop.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah I pinged fantasai on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/NOVALISTIC/status/1067838946657239040).

Comment: @BoltClock Did you hear anything from fantasai regarding this?

Comment: @Joel: No; she never replied. I guess she missed it. While I'm here, would you like me to clean up these comments?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two specific distinct questions, so I will answer them both.

> my question is: what is causing this behaviour?

To answer your question: When you float the element, it is taken out of the document flow and no longer counts as part of the content of the block in regards to pseudoelement selectors. From the CSS visual formatting spec:

> An element is called out of flow if it is floated, absolutely positioned, or is the root element.
>
> [Visual formatting model - W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html)

So in accordance with the spec, we can see the exact same result if we take the element out of the flow by using a different method, e.g. absolute positioning:

```css
.capitalizeWord::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<p class="capitalizeWord">
  <span>
    <i></i>
  test1></span>hello
</p>

<!-- example 2 -->
<p class="capitalizeWord">
  <span style="float:left;"> <!-- float causes it to work -->
    <i></i>
  test2></span>hello
</p>

<!-- example 3 -->
<p class="capitalizeWord">
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 50px"> <!-- absolute positioning causes it to work -->
    <i></i>
  test3></span>hello
</p>
```

> is there a frontend way to accomplish the result of test2 but with test1's structure?

As far as I know there is no way to do this in pure CSS, because you would necessarily need to take the offending element out of the flow to get the selector to find the desired pseudoelement. And by taking the element out of the flow, your elements would no longer have the same visual hierarchy.

> I would still classify this as a bug

The behavior follows the spec, so it is not a bug. You might argue that it's a poor design choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, However, I’m not sure you’ve covered every aspect of the bug here. See the latest 10 comments where an empty tag is discussed. Thanks

Comment: @Joel In the comments you also said "this post is not going to get an answer to its original question. It's become more about the "bug" and less so about the question at hand" and "I don't care about the 'bug', i mearly find it annoying, i just want an answer to the question(s)". That signals to me that you were indeed not looking for someone to cover the bug, but instead looking for answers to your questions. If you are now looking for someone to "cover every aspect of the bug", you might consider that the scope of your question has expanded.

Comment: @Joel I am looking at the deleted answers right now and both of the things you just said are factually untrue. There was one single answer from someone with over 70k rep, and it was the only answer to draw from the spec at all. My answer is longer than all the deleted answers including that one (which was only a one-line answer with a quote from the spec). So no, my answer has *not* been posted before, there was only that one other answer that even drew from the spec, and it was a different part of the spec than I drew from.